# Is it possible to create LOCAL property("active variable") in c#?

Tags: c#, variables

As example, there is possible to make "active" global variable(property) "Area" with auto-calculation:

```
public int Width = 5;
public int Length = 10;
public int Area
{
   get{ return Width * Length;}
}
```

But... is there is possible to make something like this but inside of a method -- local var?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for `Area` in your example is a *property*. Properties can only be declared in classes/structures.

However, you can accomplish something similar with a lambda (a special syntax that declares a function that can capture variables contextually):

```
void Method()
{
    int width = 4;
    int length = 2;
    Func<int> area = () => length * width;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", area());  // 8
    length = 3;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", area());  // 12
}
```

Comment: That's what I had search for! Thanks a lot, Cameron!

Comment: Sure, glad to help :-)